# How to sort one multiarray dict based on another array in python 2.7

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have some data(in array) which I want to sort based(Priority) on another dict
Example

```
refList = ['INDIA', 'CHINA','USA']

list = { 'Country': [], 'Reps' : []}

list['Country'].append('CHINA')
list['Reps'].append('Xuan Fo')
list['Country'].append('CHINA')
list['Reps'].append('Chan Li')
list['Country'].append('USA')
list['Reps'].append('Jhon Dugg')
list['Country'].append('USA')
list['Reps'].append('Michael Bevan')
list['Country'].append('INDIA')
list['Reps'].append('Rahul Kartik')
```

I am trying to sort the list based on the refList given country name.

I saw something like

```
newlist = sorted(list['Country'], key=lambda k: refList)
```

But it does not give me the desired output..

Any ideas? I know I am doing something wrong but I don't know how to....

I know I can iterate with

```
for key in refList:
```

and compare each entry and make a new list but for a large input list it is taking very long time to go through.

My Python doesn't have

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

The actual list(different name obviously) has data appended the way I showed.. I don't have control over it I just have the full list. I only showed in code to give idea how they are in the tree.

This is how it may look like

```
{'Country': ['CHINA', 'CHINA', 'USA', 'USA', 'INDIA'], 'Reps': ['Xuan Fo', 'Chan Li', 'Jhon Dugg', 'Michael Bevan', 'Rahul Kartik']}
```

And I want to reorder it as (with my relist priority)

```
{'Country': ['INDIA','CHINA', 'CHINA', 'USA', 'USA'], 'Reps': ['Rahul Kartik','Xuan Fo', 'Chan Li', 'Jhon Dugg', 'Michael Bevan']}
```

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/

Comment: I can't to undertand, what's the desired output?

Comment: Objects would be good for this, with a `Globe` object holding a list/dictionary of `Country` objects, each holding a list of `Representative` objects. Holding countries in one list and reps in another list seems inconvenient. Oh, and I'd recommend not reassigning the built-in function `list`.

Comment: +1 on TigerhawkT3 's comment about NOT reassigning the built-in function list as something else. That is a terrible idea !

Comment: So you have a dict called list?

Comment: You could have a list of dicts. A list entry per country and each dict holds a single country entry and a list of reps. This way you would preserve which reps are associated with which country.

Comment: The data / dict is only a sample of what I have and the List is also just mock up..I don't have control over the list..I have my own Sorting Priority in a dict. The rest is given...So from that mixed up list I need to make it sorted first and then I can have my own output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number one, don't use `list` as a variable name because it is a builtin function. I would merge your two seperate lists into a list of (rep name, country) pairs using the `zip` function.

```
d = list(zip(l['Reps'], l['Country']))
```

To sort the list, you need to look up where the country occurs in `refList` using the `index` method.

```
d.sort(key=lambda pair: refList.index(pair[1]))
```

To convert back into two lists, use zip with the splat operator:

```
l['Reps'], l['Country'] = zip(*d)
```

Comment: Turns out I was going wrong about how the dict list was produced at the beginning. It was in one single dict...your approach also working..Thanks